# What does the :any part mean to apt in a debian package dependency list?

Tags: apt, dependencies

Some packages list dependencies in their `Depends:` field like `python:any` or `perl:any`. What does the :any part mean?

Why would a package maintainer choose to list a dependency on python or perl in that way with `:any`?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a package?

Comment: An example would be Package jackd2 in ubuntu 18.04: 
Package: jackd2
Version: 1.9.12~dfsg-2build1
Depends: ..., python:any, ...

Comment: Sorry the example package in my previous comment is from ubuntu 19.10 not ubuntu 18.04, but it has this python:any dependency.

Comment: It is same on 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

The word `any` means any architecture here.

For example, on a `amd64` system any of `amd64` or `i386` will satisfy.

Comment: That means that either `amd64` or `i386` will do for python. If you force a wrong arch, the dependenci will be satisfied, but that makes no sense.

Comment: Why would a package maintainer choose to list a dependency on python or perl in that way with :any?

Comment: Because it doesn't matter for these packages. Either one will do.